# use same table multiple times in SP performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a very long lines of code in SP that performs poorly. This sp requires me to validate data from multiple select statement with the same table multiple times.

Is it a good idea to dump data from physical table into temp table first or is it ok to reference it multiple times in multiple select statement within the same SP?

Comment: How many rows in the table? Does it have indexes that are being used? Is it the same dataset each time? Most of the time the answer is that you shouldn't try and outthink the query planner, just give it correct indexes.

Comment: Data is around 3000 rows for that table. Dataset is diff for each select and indexes has been used. Im thinking to put it into temp table first since other SP will refer to this same table and our application require a lot of users to access the system at the same time so I wanna avoid this table from being lock when others try to access it.

Comment: 3,000 rows is not a problem. Indexes won't even be used on a table this size. You need to analyze and understand the real performance issue. It's not a 3,000 row table, no matter how many times you reference it or how many users use it.

Comment: It really depends on the code. Most likely it's just bad code (cursors, missing joins, incorrect use of distinct). How many tables are involved in this stored procedure and what is the largest row count? How long does it take to run and how long do you expect it to run?

Comment: the largest would be millions of records. Im trying to rewrite the whole SP as currently it can takes more than an hour to run. I wanna refactor it to its best so am considering all aspects

Comment: I can be pretty sure that loading a subset of 3,000 records into a temp table instead of referencing it multiple times won't make any difference - don't waste your time. The first step is to get a query plan for each piece of the SP and find the slowest step and fix it. Make sure you aren't needlessly using cursors or distinct

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid. I guess I will just skip this thought then.

Comment: I suggest that you add either logging or `RAISERROR` to provide timings at each point, and find out which pieces take the longest. You can also do it from the other side - use dmv's to identify long running queries

Answer (score 0):

Per your description , you would like to improve the performance.  Could you please show us your script of your SP and your execution plan? So that we have a right direction and make some test.

There are some simple yet useful tips and optimization to improve stored procedure performance.

1. Use SET NOCOUNT ON
2. Use fully qualified procedure name
3. sp_executesql instead of Execute for dynamic queries
4. Using IF EXISTS AND SELECT
5. Avoid naming user stored procedure as sp_procedurename.
6. Use set based queries wherever possible.
7. Keep transaction short and crisp

For more details , you can refer to it ： https://www.sqlservergeeks.com/improve-stored-procedure-performance-in-sql-server/

If you think it does not satisfy your requirement, please share us more information.

Best Regards,

Rachel

Comment: Thanks for the tips but I am afraid that I am not able to post the whole SP here as it is almost 2000 lines of codes.

Answer (score 0):

> > Is it a good idea to dump data from physical table into temp table first or is it ok to reference it multiple times in multiple select statement within the same SP?

If it is a local temp table, each session using this stored procedure will create a separate temp table for themselves, although it will reduce the weight on original table, but it will increase the usage of memory and tempdb.

If it is a global temp table, we can only create one for all session, then we will need to create one manually before someone using it and then delete it if it is useless.

For me, I will use the Indexed Views, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Actually, using global temp table can be a good option, but you will need to create one every time the SQL Server Service starts.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without the detail. However with such a large SP and such a small table it is likely that a particular select or join is slow rather than just repeatedly hitting the table (SQL server is perfectly happy to cache bits of tables or indexes in memory).

If possible can you get the execution plan of each part of the SP? or log some timings? or run each bit with statistics on?

That will tell you which bit is slow and we can help you fix it.